# How to load balance SOLR server? Is Redis a good solution?

Tags: solr, load-balancing, redis

I am writing a web app that will be hitting a SOLR server frequently. I plan to create multiple instances of this SOLR server so that one specific server doesn't get hit too much. What's the best way to load balance this?

I was thinking of creating a Redis store that would store the number of current requests per SOLR server, and querying on this store to get the SOLR server with the least # of current requests. Of course, I would update this store everytime a request is done.

Is this the best approach? What would you do in this situation?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm guessing you already set up [Solr replication](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolrReplication). Now, since Solr is a standard HTTP application, you can use any generic HTTP load balancer, such as [HAProxy](http://haproxy.1wt.eu/) or [Varnish](http://www.varnish-cache.org/trac/wiki/LoadBalancing). See [this article](http://davehall.com.au/blog/dave/2010/03/13/solr-replication-load-balancing-haproxy-and-drupal) on setting up HAProxy with Solr.

Comment: Is there any open source HTTP load balancer running on Windows without any Linux shell help (e.g. cgywin)

Comment: @ScottChu IIRC there's something like it in IIS, but I wouldn't bother. Just use Linux.

Answer (score 4):

There is an existing load balancing solution for Solr, discussed [here](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolrCloud): have you looked at that?

Comment: I believe that SolrCloud is NOT a full load balancing solution. While it distributes requests across the cluster, you are still directly accessing Solr servers, and if the one you've chosen to access the cloud through goes down, so will your requests.